# Angular-Material: Md-slider dots not showing within directive template

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using the MD-Slider with the md-discrete option to display the ticks on the track.
Strangely though the ticks of the slider within a directive template are not displayed. But outside the directive it works.

I have added a screenshot to show you. See the JADE code for this example:

```
div.sliding-footer-panel(ng-class="{ open: openFooter}" layout="column")
  div.trigger(layout="column"  layout-align="center center" ng-click="openFooter=!openFooter")
    md-icon(ng-hide="openFooter" md-svg-icon="hardware:ic_keyboard_arrow_up_24px")
    md-icon(ng-show="openFooter" md-svg-icon="hardware:ic_keyboard_arrow_down_24px")

  md-slider.md-primary(md-discrete flex min="-0.5" max="4" step="0.5" aria-label="Change play rate")

  div.footerContent(layout="column" flex)
    audio-player
```

[image]

The directive `audio-player` loads the `<audio>` tag and the slider next to it.
The slide above the footerContent div is rendered correctly in the main view and renders the dots.

When I look at the canvas tag within the track element I see that its dimensions are 0. The one loaded outside the directive has normal dimensions.

[image: screenshot]

So I recon the CANVAS tag is not loaded correctly via the directive. Anyone an idea how to fix this?